# Passing multiple total value to another component

Tags: reactjs, components, undefined, react-props

[Example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouea1.png)

I want to push multiple total value to another component

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBP36.png)

Comment: Attach image to see how your components are structured.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2873538)